# Google Apps Scripts API for Google Docs Table

Tags: google-drive, google-fusion-tables

If we take a look at Google Apps Script we can see API related to just about everything **except** [Google Docs Fusion Tables](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/?hl=en) that are supposed to be some sort of lightweight database tables.

Can anybody tell me whether we can access those using Google Apps Scripts? And how... Why? Because we could build even better dynamic Google Sites since these tables have indexes and are definitely faster than using Spreadsheets.

Just to make it clear. I'm talking about *these* tables:

[image]

Comment: If you mean the tables in Google Docs Documents, then I don't think so. They are just a feature in the text of the document. I guess you could parse the text to find them, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @benregn: I've updated my question and added an image to make it completely clear which tables I'm talking about. Not the ones, you mentioned in your comment. But those shown in above image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official support for Google Fusion Tables in Google Apps Scripts as at Feb 2012. However, there is a sample App Scripts projects that provides simple CRUD wrapper against the [Google Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/)

You can install the sample project by going to the `Insert` menu and selecting `Script` then searching for "Fusion"

[image: Fusion API wrapper project]

Install this project and you will be able to query the Fusion Tables API via Google Apps Scripts.

Comment: The Google Apps Script Gallery was deprecated. Ref. [Release note](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2014#june_2014)

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Nowadays Fusion Tables can be accessed from Google Apps Script as an advanced service.

## Extended answer

Google Apps Script has two built-in ways to interact with other Google services

- Built-in Google Services also called G Suite Services
- Advanced Google Services

The available services are listed on the left panel of https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/

[image]

The instructions to enable an avanced service are listed on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

Basically you should first enable the advanced service prior to use it.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/